# How to backup Clash of Clan?

Tags: backup, clash-of-clans

[image]

How do I backup this game? I'm using a Nokia XL phone.

Comment: I'm writing solution for "how to add google services in nokia xl?" Nokia xl doesn't support google apps hence you can't backup app data which rely on google play services. There are ways to flash google apps and play services in nokia xl. You can find some solutions here: http://www.androidrootguide.com/2015/02/root-nokia-xl-install-gapps.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you signed in with a Google account on your phone? If not, do so.

Next, do you have Google Play Games installed and a Google Play Games profile? If not, install it and/or create a profile.

Finally, in Clash of Clans, click Settings and connect your Google account. This will backup your game to your Google account, and any time you sign in with it you'll be able to play your save. You may wish to optionally also connect your Facebook account while you're here.